# Concating Values for rows in Oracle

Tags: oracle, concatenation

I have a query in Oracle that does a group by on Field1.  This Query returns 2 Rows, however, row1 has a count of 2 on field1.  I'd like to display the both Field1 values in a single cell on row1.  Is this possible?

Comment: Oracle doesn't have a built-in concat-like aggregate function.  If these values are distinct why do you want them in the same row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tim Hall has a collection of the different [string aggregation techniques](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/StringAggregationTechniques.php) available in Oracle.  Depending on the Oracle version, I would generally prefer the built-in LISTAGG analytic function (for 11.2) or the user-defined aggregate function for earlier releases.

Comment: I'm partial to COLLECT myself on 10g.

Answer (score 0):

Counts of two are easy, just a MIN(field1)||','||MAX(field1)

You may want to cater for two rows with the same value differently:

CASE WHEN MIN(field1) != MAX(field1) THEN MIN(field1)||','||MAX(field1) ELSE MIN(field1) END

Answer (score 0):

Writing a small stored procedure is sometimes easiest, because you can control the formatting independently of number.  The other answers may be better, but this is quicker if you're familiar with PL/SQL.